# Is it possible to separate voices coming to a single channel at runtime (karaoke principle)?

Tags: android, audio, ffmpeg, media

I wonder if it is possible to filter separately two voices at runtime? Let's say, you're listening to a song and there is a singer (voice A) and you're singing as well (voice B), like in karaoke. My only guess - is to filter out any noise by NoiseSuppressor API and then measure the sound intensity, and assume that the voice A will have 40db and voice B - 50db (which is definitely not the way to go bc songs are mostly not linear like that). Maybe there is a way with using pitches/frequency? If yes, is there any tool which could help me? Or algo? I searched for this in the FFMPEG documentation and read some articles, but it seems like it's extremely hard - because I will have the only channel (an android device) that receives both sounds - your singing and singer's singing.

So maybe somebody could guide me on the right path where to look or what I could use/read?

Comment: Looking at similar problem, android recording, then to linux `ffmpeg`, using [lffmpeg mono2stereo](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation#monostereo), then taking out the duplication...Also thinking to make an empty stereo of total length mono, and writing to empty... and then using (in my case) [whisper.cpp](https://github.com/ggerganov/whisper.cpp), where you'll see a karaoke example. Annoying to have to get your own singer1 from ->to singer 2 from -> to... but my snippets are very short. Sigh

Comment: @Chris wow, thanks a lot! I'll take a look at your links!

Comment: I'm edging up on a kindergardener's `ffmpeg` that could clearly be done better that I'll share when complete. At the moment I can't map commands to multiple channels, or figure out the proper notation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my example I have a short snippet of 8 sec from an 8 min .mp4 monorecording of two speakers. In the 8 sec clip, 'ownership' of words is as follows, speaker1=X, speaker2=Y
{XXXXX YYYYY XX} across the 12 words. For the purposes of advancing further to `whisper.cpp` I have already resampled to .wav and 'shot logged' (take secs per speaker per ownership) in `audacity`, though with a little more attention could have forgone speaker1's last two words. The idea, overall is to silence one speaker or another, here speaker1 has to be silenced twice in speaker2's result.

```
# we start with two copies of our mono
# ffmpeg -i repit.wav repit1.wav; ffmpeg -i repit.wav repit2.wav
# this renaming could be `cp repit.wav repit1.wav` without ffmpeg
#take speaker1 first 5 words to silence 0:5 secs
ffmpeg -i repit1.wav -af "volume=enable='between(t,0,5)':volume=0" repit1_si1.wav 
#take the trailing speaker1 words out 7.7:8 secs
ffmpeg -i repit1_si1.wav -af "volume=enable='between(t,7.7,8)':volume=0" repit1_si2.wav
# silence speaker2 in speaker1 5:7.7 secs
ffmpeg -i repit2.wav -af "volume=enable='between(t,5,7.7)':volume=0" repit2_sil1.wav

# and the magic, found thru reading the manual (rtm), a deficit we both suffer
ffmpeg -i repit1_si2.wav -i repit2_sil1.wav -filter_complex "[0:a][1:a]join=inputs=2:channel_layout=stereo[a]" -map "[a]" repit_12.wav
play repit_12.wav # and we see it is indeed stereo...
```

The recording session set up was speaker1 on a tablet with essentially a directional mike, and speaker2 on the other side of the desk. This resulted in low volume for speaker2 that was adjusted by:

```
ffmpeg -i repit_12.wav -af "dynaudnorm=f=150:g=15" repit_12_2.wav
```

`whisper.cpp` is deceptively easy to build, git clone, cd into dir, cmake ., make, install - et viola. install your models (en - english). Examples have main in whisper.cpp/main, though so far, as I haven't mucked with the put what where in the cmake, my main writes to whisper.cpp/bin/main, and I copied it over to whisper.cpp/main. Next to see if I can get `--diarize` going. In your obviously more extensive 'song' length project, you might consider creating an accompanying blank video, to timestamp (at least this is how I imagine it might work, more rtm to do).

```
# on to whisper.cpp on (now) separated files
# separate  
ffmpeg -i repit_12_2.wav -map_channel 0.0.0 repit_speaker1.wav -map_channel 0.0.1 repit_speaker2.wav
~/whisper.cpp$ ./main -f /home/chris/MMSE_audio/repit_speaker2.wav -ml 1
whisper_model_load: loading model from 'models/ggml-base.en.bin'
whisper_model_load: n_vocab       = 51864
whisper_model_load: n_audio_ctx   = 1500
whisper_model_load: n_audio_state = 512
whisper_model_load: n_audio_head  = 8
whisper_model_load: n_audio_layer = 6
whisper_model_load: n_text_ctx    = 448
whisper_model_load: n_text_state  = 512
whisper_model_load: n_text_head   = 8
whisper_model_load: n_text_layer  = 6
whisper_model_load: n_mels        = 80
whisper_model_load: f16           = 1
whisper_model_load: type          = 2
whisper_model_load: adding 1607 extra tokens
whisper_model_load: mem_required  =  506.00 MB
whisper_model_load: ggml ctx size =  140.60 MB
whisper_model_load: memory size   =   22.83 MB
whisper_model_load: model size    =  140.54 MB

system_info: n_threads = 4 / 4 | AVX = 0 | AVX2 = 0 | AVX512 = 0 | NEON = 0 | F16C = 0 | FP16_VA = 0 | WASM_SIMD = 0 | BLAS = 1 | 

main: processing '/home/chris/MMSE_audio/repit_speaker2.wav' (128000 samples, 8.0 sec), 4 threads, 1 processors, lang = en, task = transcribe, timestamps = 1 ...


[00:00:00.000 --> 00:00:00.000]  
[00:00:00.000 --> 00:00:01.180]   No
[00:00:01.180 --> 00:00:01.280]   "
[00:00:01.280 --> 00:00:02.120]  if
[00:00:02.120 --> 00:00:02.600]  s
[00:00:02.600 --> 00:00:03.000]  "
[00:00:03.000 --> 00:00:03.750]   and
[00:00:03.750 --> 00:00:03.990]  /
[00:00:03.990 --> 00:00:04.480]  or
[00:00:04.480 --> 00:00:04.720]   "
[00:00:04.720 --> 00:00:05.470]  but
[00:00:05.470 --> 00:00:05.710]  s
[00:00:05.710 --> 00:00:06.000]  "
[00:00:07.600 --> 00:00:09.600]   Okay


whisper_print_timings:     load time =   592.37 ms
whisper_print_timings:      mel time =   281.91 ms
whisper_print_timings:   sample time =    29.47 ms
whisper_print_timings:   encode time = 392814.88 ms / 65469.14 ms per layer
whisper_print_timings:   decode time = 32602.80 ms / 5433.80 ms per layer
whisper_print_timings:    total time = 426371.59 ms
```

Takes a while on an old sse4 chipset. And you have a different goal that is likely addressed in examples on `whisper.cpp` site.